# Drawer layout - navigation header is scrolling ANDROID

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation, navigation-drawer

I've got a problem. There is a a scrollable menu, but the Textview is scrolling too. I don't want to scrolling it.

Here is main XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarInner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_app_bar_layout">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:paddingStart="16dp"
                app:tabPaddingStart="16dp"
                app:tabPaddingEnd="16dp"
                app:tabMinWidth="96dp"
                app:tabGravity="center" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_wallet_id"
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_total_credits"
            android:layout_width="182dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"/>

        <!--<FrameLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom"-->
            <!--android:background="@color/md_white_1000"-->
            <!--android:elevation="4dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginBottom="-96dp">-->

            <!--<Button android:id="@+id/navigation_button_footer"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:text=""-->
                <!--android:textSize="13sp"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@color/md_grey_800"-->
                <!--android:lines="3"-->
                <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                <!--style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"-->
                <!--android:paddingTop="20dp"-->
                <!--android:paddingLeft="20dp"-->
                <!--android:paddingRight="20dp"-->
                <!--android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>-->

        <!--</FrameLayout>-->

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_connection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/actmain_margintop"
        android:background="#3c3c3c"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_error"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/error_no_internet"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twentyfive" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_dialog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/error_no_internet"
                android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/twentyfive" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I mean about this @+id/nav_drawer_total_credits for example.

**EDIT**

Here is **nav_drawer_header.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@color/material_color_primary">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/drawer_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Widget.Toolbar.Title"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Widget.Toolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>


    <TextView android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_total_credits"
        android:layout_width="182dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Credits:"/>


    <TextView android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_wallet_id"
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Wallet ID:"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

And the JAVA code:

```
    mDrawerLayout   = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.END);




    mDrawerLay      = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    mDrawerLay.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    navigationTotalCreditTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_total_credits);
    navigationTotalCreditTextView.setText("Total Credits: " + PreferenceConnector.readInteger(aiContext,
            PreferenceConnector.WALLETPOINTS, 0));

    navigationWalletIDText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_wallet_id);
    navigationWalletIDText.setText("Wallet ID: " + PreferenceConnector.readString(aiContext,
            PreferenceConnector.WALLETID, ""));

    navigationUsernameText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_username);
    navigationUsernameText.setText(PreferenceConnector.readString(aiContext,
            PreferenceConnector.USERNAME, ""));
```

[Here is how it should be and how it is when no scrolling menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPj8C.png)

[Here is how it looks like after scrolling down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJjaU.png)